# gsub returns \n (newline)

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have this behaviour of regex which I can't explain. My goal is to parse only the text after the `@` yet when my string contains `\n` preceded by some words, `gsub` parses also `\n`:

```
string <- ".@address something \n"
gsub("^\\.?@([a-z0-9_]{1,15})[^a-z0-9_]+.*$", "\\1", string, perl=T);
# [1] "address\n"
string <- ".@address \n"
gsub("^\\.?@([a-z0-9_]{1,15})[^a-z0-9_]+.*$", "\\1", string, perl=T);
# [1] "address"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl-compatible regular expressions `.` does not match `\n`. This is in contrast to "normal" regular expressions. Have a look at this example:

```
grepl(".", "\n", perl = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
grepl(".", "\n", perl = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE
```

Your code will work if you specify `perl = FALSE`:

```
gsub("^\\.?@([a-z0-9_]{1,15})[^a-z0-9_]+.*$", "\\1", string, perl = FALSE)
# [1] "address"
```

Comment: You could make dot to match even new line character also by adding `s` modifier at the veryfirst. Try `grepl("(?s).", "\n", perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

To extract `address`, you could also use:

```
library(stringr)
 str_extract(string, perl('(?<=@)[a-z0-9_]+(?= )'))
#[1] "address"
```